how to find date of nth occurrence of a particular day of the week (e.g. Sunday) in a particular month in gnu date bash
I want to find the date for the third Sunday of the month for a given month using the gnu date command in bash.
I know that one can write this to find the next Sunday from now:
 date +%Y%m%d -d "next sunday" 

(and could then add n weeks), but after reading the man page I don't see how to do this relative to a particular date, e.g. like
 date +%Y%m%d -d "20221001+next sunday" 

or actually
 date +%Y%m%d -d "20221001+next sunday+2 weeks" 

I've found this specific question answered for a lot of other languages on SO, or this similar question for gnu date in bash, but not this specific question using gnu date.

Does the solution have to use the GNU date command (presumably plus some surrounding other bash code/Unix tools) or would a solution using, say, GNU awk work instead?

awk would work too, apologies, I was just thinking that a gdate solution might be the most straightforward

See How to get the date of the 3. wednesday in the month.

You could calculate it starting with the weekday %w of the first day in that month:
n=3        # The third
w=0        # Sunday (0=Sun .. 6=Sat)
ym=202411  # in November 24
d=$(((n-1)*7+(w-$(date +%w -d $ym'01')+7)%7+1))

echo $d    # gives 17


Wow! Date Math Supreme!

Wow, was thinking the same...

This might work for you (GNU touch & date):
touch -d '20221001 -1 day' file && 
touch -d 'third sunday' -r file file && 
date +%Y%m%d -r file && 
rm file

Use touch twice to create a file with the correct day and date to output the correct format.
N.B. The edge case where a Sunday is the first day of the month thus pmf's suggestion. If the OP wanted the third Sunday from an input date, then forgo the -1 day in the first touch command.

Alternative using GNU parallel, ncal and awk:
parallel -n2 'ncal {1} {2}|awk "/Su/{print {2}{1}\$4}"' ::: 01 2022 11 2024


If the queried month happens to start with the day in question (for Sunday, e.g. Dec 2024), the file approach actually would yield the date of the fourth Sunday, because third sunday only starts counting from tomorrow. But changing the first command to touch -d '… -1day' file && … solves the issue.

@pmf thanks I've amended the solution for the edge case.
